# Visual Basic guarda mal archivo de texto

Tags: java, vb.net, vb

Buenas, estoy realizando un proyecto con Processing, y Visual Basic.
Tengo una aplicacion exportada con processing que toma la resolucion de la ventana de un archivo de texto.
Estoy programando un launcher en visual basic en el cual se puede seleccionar la resolucion que se desea, y esto lo que hace es escribir en ese archivo de texto, para cuando ejecute la aplicacion de processing, utilice la resolucion deseada.
Mi problema es que al modificar el archivo de texto manualmente, la aplicacion se ejecuta en dichas resoluciones. Pero al modificarlo mediante el launcher, la aplicacion no se ejecuta.

El codigo de Vb

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ComboBox1.Text = "1920x1080" Then
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\data\resolucion.txt", False)
        file.WriteLine("1920")
        file.WriteLine("1080")
        file.Close()
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text = "1280x720" Then
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\data\resolucion.txt", False)
        file.WriteLine("1280")
        file.WriteLine("720")
        file.Close()



    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text = "800x600" Then


        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\data\resolucion.txt", False)
        file.WriteLine(800)
        file.WriteLine(600)
        file.Close()
     End If
End Sub`
```

Archivo editado manualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Arhivo editado mediante VB:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Como queda el archivo que modificas via el launcher? recibe cambios o no cambia nunca? estas seguro que estas mirando el archivo correcto no?

Comment: El archivo queda con las dos lineas que debe llevar, una linea con 1920 o 1280 o 800, y la de abajo con 1080 o 720 o 600. Lo escribe perfectamente. El problema es que no me ejecuta la aplicacion. Pero si el archivo lo modifico yo si la ejecuta.

Comment: que tiene que ver java aqui. Entonces cual es el problema? porque mostras el codigo para grabar el archivo, pero si eso anda, donde esta el problema?

Comment: Processing es java, fuera de ello. El problema es que no ejecuta la aplicacion cuando escribo la resolucion mediante vb. Quizas me falte algun permiso, o lo este restrigiendo mediante vb

Comment: por favor mira los links que te pase. De que aplicacion hablas? aca mostras codigo para grabar el archivo, y la pantalla que mostras es la de la resolucion de la pantalla. Si tu pregunta es, no puedo ejecutar un programa desde otro programa, entonces el titulo deberia ser ese, y el cuerpo de la pregunta sobre eso. Tal vez el problema no sea como guarda el archivo VB. Probaste ejecutarlo manualmente despues de los cambios de VB?

Comment: Hablo de la aplicacion que toma la resolucion del archivo resolucion.txt. Si escribo la resolucion mediante VB, y ejecuto la aplicacion manualmente tampoco funciona.

Comment: Entonces el problema es como graba el archivo VB. Podrias mostrar eso, mirando en hexadecimal, pq puede ser que grabe basura antes o despues en el archivo de texto.

Comment: Como podria mirar eso?

Comment: con algun editor de texto como notepad++

Comment: Ahora investigo como resolverlo, intente renombrando un archivo, al nombre resolucion.txt y asi funciona, pero necesito poder escribir, ya que si no tendria que hacer un reordenamiento y reescribir todos los archivos cada vez que seleccione otra opcion de resolucion

Answer (score 1):

Ya he resuelto el problema.
Al escribir el archivo debia usar lo siguiente;

```
Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\data\resolucion.txt", False, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(437))
        sw.WriteLine("1920")
        sw.WriteLine("1080")
        sw.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "1280x720" Then
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\data\resolucion.txt", False)
    file.WriteLine("1920")
    file.WriteLine("1080")
    file.Close()
```

El writeLine no deberia ser 1280 y 720?

Igual no es la respuesta pero ahi yo ya veo un fallo o no... saludos.

Comment: Deberia ser asi, pero es insignificante, fijate las imagenes que agregue, como queda el archivo visto en HEX

Comment: Eso puede ser por que cuando escribes en el fichero escribe un objeto de cabecera, entonces el primer objeto que lee siempre será la cabecera y luego la primera resolucion de pixels la segunda no llega, mira  a ver eso y me dices :)

Comment: Exactamente es eso, escribe un objeto de cabecera y es lo que no deseo.

Comment: Pues o reescribes el metodo header y lo dejas en blanco creando tu porpio stream wirter o lees siempre la cabecera y luego ya lees la resolucion y la aplicas

Comment: Como podria reescribir el metodo header? La verdad que no se como hacerlo

Comment: Tendras que crearte una clase y hacerle un extends de la clase StreamWriter importando todos los abstract y modificando solo el del header, y en vez de llamar añ StreamWriter llamas a la clase que acabas de crear. Pero igual te es mas facil leer siempre la cabecera y que no haga nada para que salte al siguiente objeto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que lo que ves es un archivo de texto plano que lleva consigo caracteres especiales, tu lo que necesitas es saber el modo de acceso binario de un archivo para que eso no te pase, te paso el código aquí:

```
Public Function FileWriteData(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal FileData As String) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        FileDelete(FilePath)
        Dim NumFile As Integer

        FileWriteData = False

        NumFile = vb.FileSystem.FreeFile
        vb.FileSystem.FileOpen(NumFile, FilePath, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Write, OpenShare.Shared)
        vb.FileSystem.FilePut(NumFile, FileData)
        vb.FileSystem.FileClose()

        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            FileWriteData = True
        End If

    End Function

Public Function FileReadData(ByVal FilePath As String) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim NumFile As Integer, Datos As String, SubDatos As String
        Dim Man As Long, LenghtTempo As Long, LongitudSP As Integer

        FileReadData = vbNullString

        Datos = vbNullString

        NumFile = vb.FileSystem.FreeFile
        FileOpen(NumFile, FilePath, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Function
        SubDatos = vbNullString
        LenghtTempo = LOF(NumFile)

        If LenghtTempo > 50000 Then
            For Man = 1 To LenghtTempo Step 50000
                LongitudSP = LenghtTempo - Man
                If LongitudSP < 50000 Then
                    Datos = Datos & Space(LongitudSP)
                    FileGet(NumFile, Datos)
                    SubDatos = SubDatos & Datos
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Datos = Datos & Space(50000)
                    FileGet(NumFile, Datos)
                    SubDatos = SubDatos & Datos
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Datos = Datos & Space(LenghtTempo)
            FileGet(NumFile, Datos)
            SubDatos = Datos
        End If

        FileReadData = SubDatos
        vb.FileSystem.FileClose()
    End Function
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esto es VB6, no vb.net. Hay que tener en cuenta las etiquetas de la pregunta